# How do I update my LineageOS installation?

Tags: lineageos

I have a Motorola Moto E LTE 2nd Generation Android phone (`surnia`) running LineageOS 14.1.20170303-NIGHTLY-surnia.

I installed LineageOS by following the instructions in the wiki: unlocking the bootloader, writing TeamWin's recovery program, wiping the partitions and installing LineageOS and OpenGApps Pico from the zip files.

Now that I have my phone running smoothly, I'd like to keep it up-to-date and secure.

- How do I update LineageOS?

Is there a setting on the phone that I need to enable to have passive updates? Or is there an option I can activate to update to the latest build when I've backed up my data and I'm ready to proceed?

I can't find any information on the LineageOS wiki regarding updates.

I could update LineageOS by going back into TeamWin and writing the latest .zip, but that seems a bit drastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to your phone’s settings, then “About phone”, you’ll see the phone’s status with an entry at the very top called “LineageOS updates”. In there you can configure how often your phone should check for updates, and you’ll also see a list of available updates. You can tap the “Download” button to download an update, and once it’s finished downloading, the button will say “Install” and tapping that will reboot your phone to TWRP and install the update.

Answer (score 0):

Since other answers were correct but are now outdated, on my Lineage 19, I went to ⚙ **Settings > System** and found the **Updater** in that menu.

More instructions can be found in [LineageOS.org](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/channel/update/)'s Wiki.